# php Object of class DateInterval could not be converted to string

Tags: php, datetime, date-math, dateinterval

i've tried using date_diff and date_create to get a difference from two date that's already converted to string.

here's the code:

```
$date_1 = date_create();
$date_now = date_format($date_1, 'Y-m-d');


//echo $date_now . "\n";
$date=date_create($date_now);
date_add($date,date_interval_create_from_date_string("3 days"));
$date_return =  date_format($date,"Y-m-d");


$diff = date_diff(date_create($date_now), date_create($date_return));

echo $diff;
```

and i am getting this error:

```
Object of class DateInterval could not be converted to string
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You need to call [`DateInterval::format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) to display that difference as a string.

```
echo $diff->format('%d days');
```

See the manual for all of the available formatting options.

Comment: that does it.. thanks for the reference and the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Using Carbon(A simple PHP API extension for DateTime) could be something like this

```
   $date_now->diffInDays($date_return);
```

hope this helps. But to get more information about Carbon follow this link [Carbon Docs](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)