# php Greater Than Comparison Not Working

Tags: php, string, int

I'm looking to highlight the rows when a child is 12 years and older but all the rows are highlighting.

In a nutshell, here is my data.

I'm getting the birth date here:

```
      // getting birth date to a string
        $birthDateIn=strtotime($birthDate);
        $newDate=date('Y-m-d',$birthDateIn);
```

I'm getting the age of the child as of today here:

```
        // getting the date difference between birthdate and today
        $birthDateIn = new DateTime(''.$newDate.'');
        $todayDateIn = new DateTime('today');
        $age = $birthDateIn->diff($todayDateIn);
```

I'm looping through the MySQL query results, and then displaying the age in this format:

```
        echo "<td>" . $age->format('%y years %m months') ."</td>";
```

Then, this code sets age of child in 2020 (this works):

```
        //Get age Dec 2020  
        $setDec2020 = new DateTime('2020-12-31');           
        $ageOnDec2020=$birthDateIn->diff($setDec2020);
```

Now, here is my problem.  I'm using this code to display a GREEN span if the age of the child will be over 12 years of age, otherwise, yellow:

```
        if ($ageOnDec2020 > 12)
        {   
            $ageOnDec2020Display = "<span style='background-color: #98FB98'>".$ageOnDec2020->format('%y') ."</span>";
        } else {

            $ageOnDec2020Display= "<span style='background-color: #FFFF00'>".$ageOnDec2020->format('%y') ."</span>";
        }
```

Then, I display it as such:

```
            echo "<td>" . $ageOnDec2020Display ."</td>";
```

The output is that everything is highlighting as yellow when not all of the values are over 12.  I think this has to do with "strings" and "integers" in my "if" statement -- but not sure what to do next.

Any ideas?

Comment: check the value of ageOnDec2020  variable before the IF loop

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28621270/php-object-of-class-dateinterval-could-not-be-converted-to-string

Comment: Thanks.  I just added this and it worked: ($ageOnDec2020->format('%y') > 12)

Comment: $ageOnDec2020->format('%R%a days') will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Lucky Chingi direction, I just added this to my IF statement, and all is good with the world:

```
  ($ageOnDec2020->format('%y') > 12)
```